# Tiling over rough uneven plaster wall

Tags: bathroom, repair, walls, tile, plaster

After pulling down some paneling in our bathroom I discovered why they had it there in the first place. At one time there was plastic tile over the walls and they damaged the surface while removing them. I want to tile the walls but I'm concerned that the areas where the skim coat was chipped away will make my install uneven. The skim is maybe 1/16 of an inch thick, so is that really enough to worry about? Reskimming this would be a hassle, and I know I need to fill in areas where the damage is deeper. Is it even enough of a difference to worry about?

Details: The wall is OPPOSITE the shower, so I'm not concerned with waterproofing. I'll be using 13x13 tiles. The wall is plaster board with an additional 1/2" plaster on top, so it's nearly an inch thick and very sturdy. No way am I tearing it out.

Comment: I dont think I would tile over a mess like what you describe. With the big tiles it might hold up I would try to make the wall as flat as possible prior to installing the tile.

Comment: You don't want to tear it out. Whatever you end up doing will take 2-3 times as long as tearing it out and putting in a fresh, flat surface, but hey, it's your house. Or, of course, you can "save lots of time and effort" and tile over a sketchy substrate; then wait for the tiles to fall off. Short-term time-savings, longer term you have to go back and do it over...